# getServerSideProps breaks routing in NextJS/Capacitor

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, capacitor

I use the following method to avoid exporting getServerSideProps when building with nextjs:

```
export const getServerSideProps = process.env.SKIP_SSR ? undefined : async (ctx) => { ... }
```

And I build with:

```
"build:ios": "SKIP_SSR=1 next build && SKIP_SSR=1 next export && npx cap copy ios",
```

This works really well except that when exported and run as an iOS app navigations do not work.

To make it as simple as possible, I have added this in pages/index.tsx:

```
  if(!route.asPath.startsWith('/p/home'))
    route.push('/p/home')
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      I am here in the root page {window.location.href}
    </div>
  )
```

Which is outputting: "I am here in the root page capacitor://localhost/p/home"

The page I want to see rendered is actually in /p/home/index.tsx but what renders is pages/index.

I found out the cause of this is getServerSideProps, even though I skip ssr somehow it's getting through on the build and breaking routing in Capacitor.

If I comment out getServerSideProps it runs fine.

Is there a way to properly remove getServerSideProps when doing a build?

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same problem and solved it using a webpack plugin [preprocessor-loader](https://github.com/afterwind-io/preprocessor-loader).

1. Install `webpack-preprocessor-loader` to devDepencies

```bash
$ yarn add -D webpack-preprocessor-loader
```

2. Set webpack config

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'webpack-preprocessor-loader',
          options: {
            params: {
              // handle this bool parameter via env 
              isWeb: process.env.IS_WEB,
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    })

    return config
  }
}
```

3. Write `#!if` and `#!endif` comment around getServerSideProps

```js
// yourpage.tsx

import { GetServerSidePropsContext, InferGetServerSidePropsType, NextPage } from 'next'

type PropsType = InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps> | undefined
const Page: NextPage<PropsType> = (props) => { /* your page component */ }

// #!if isWeb
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  return {
     props: yourProps
  }
}
// #!endif

export default Page
```

4. Set environment variables according to the target of the build and perform the build.

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:web": "IS_WEB=true next build",
    "build:native": "next build && next export && cp -R ./public/* ./out"
  }
}
```